# Handle three buttons click event in custom notification in android

Tags: android, android-notifications, buttonclick

I have a custom notification with three buttons ("ok", "cancel", "later")
I can catch click event only when there is one button, but with the three buttons i can't know which button of them is clicked.
My question is "How to know which button is clicked?"

```
// I use this code in My "createNotification" function to add event to buttons
Intent intent = new Intent(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendinghomeIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);
notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.okButt, pendingrecentAppIntent);
notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.cancelButt, pendingrecentAppIntent);
notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.laterButt, pendingrecentAppIntent);
```

I craeted a service to register and unregister the broadcast receiver and this is done perfectly in case of one button.
With the three buttons, when i click on each of them the same result (which is implemeneted in onReceive function) is happened,
but i want for each of them a different result.

Please help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to use separate `PendingIntents`(made from `Intents` with differecnt actions) for every button. Later in `onReceive()` you just check action of incoming `Intent` & execute different code depending on that.

Comment: thanks for replying and you are right and i already try this, but when use okIntent.putExtra("do_action", "1"); cancelIntent.putExtra("do_action", "2"); laterIntent.putExtra("do_action", "3"); and when check it in onReceive() by using intent.getExtras().get("do_action").equals("1")  a NullPointerException occurs

Comment: and how to make Intents with different actions?

Answer (score 1):

As Sam said, "You need to use separate PendingIntents(made from Intents with different actions) for every button."
I found that i must use separate PendingIntents for every button but the concept of "different actions" not worked for me. I used the second parameter of setOnClickPendingIntent to distinguish between the three PendingIntents with use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT for the fourth parameter.
My code is

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Bundle yesBundle = new Bundle();            
    yesBundle.putInt("userAnswer", 1);
    homeIntent.putExtras(yesBundle);
    PendingIntent pendinghomeIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, homeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.homeButt, pendinghomeIntent);

    Intent recentAppIntent = new Intent(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Bundle recentAppBundle = new Bundle();   
    recentAppBundle.putInt("userAnswer", 2);
    recentAppIntent.putExtras(recentAppBundle);
    PendingIntent pendingrecentAppIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, recentAppIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.recentAppButt, pendingrecentAppIntent);

    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();            
    settingsBundle.putInt("userAnswer", 3);
    settingsIntent.putExtras(settingsBundle);
    PendingIntent pendingsettingsIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 2, settingsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.settingsButt, pendingsettingsIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

and onReceive() code is

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle answerBundle = intent.getExtras();
        int userAnswer = answerBundle.getInt("userAnswer");
        if(userAnswer == 1) {
            Log.v("shuffTest","Pressed Home");
        }else if(userAnswer == 2) {
            Log.v("shuffTest","Pressed Recent App");
        }else if(userAnswer == 3) {
            Log.v("shuffTest","Pressed Settings");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am guessing notification view is your inflated view. Right?

Answer (score 1):

before two days i was stuck on same problem,i found that i was not specifiying seperate action for every pending intent, like

```
  Intent recentApIntent = new Intent(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   recentApIntent.setAction("Action 1"); 
    Bundle recentAppBundle = new Bundle();   
    recentAppBundle.putInt("userAnswer", 2);
    recentAppIntent.putExtras(recentAppBundle);
    PendingIntent pendingrecentAppIntent = 
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, recentAppIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.recentAppButt, pendingrecentAppIntent);
```

Similarly separate each intent with action and when receive broadcast identify intent.getAction() and perform task