# How can I add button on notification FCM Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

How I add **button on notification FCM** and how I add click event on that buttons. I need two buttons on notification

How I add click event on button on notification FCM Android like this image Dismiss and Answer

[image]

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void createNotification( String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this , ResultActivity. class );
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
        PendingIntent resultIntents = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Android Tutorial Point FCM Tutorial")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.switches, "Hello", resultIntents)
                .addAction(R.drawable.call, "Call", resultIntent)
                .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just a regular android notification. Please show your code to handle the fcm notifications

Comment: you can follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925688/adding-button-action-in-custom-notification

Answer (score 1):

From API level 4.1 you can add action buttons to notification. To see the basics about notification check the [android doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)
and for some more help you can check this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516722/android-notification-with-buttons-on-it/10959343#10959343) and this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

```
//Here in intent your will need provide the class which you want to open on button click in notification
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

// Build notification
// Actions are just fake
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
        .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "More", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent).build();
```

Comment: how i add click event on button

Comment: You need add to diffrent pending action on addAction() method in notification builder..i have edited the answer

Comment: give me an example @ Burhanuddin Rashid for click event code

Comment: [Example 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911744/handle-three-buttons-click-event-in-custom-notification-in-android),[Example 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396318/adding-onclick-action-to-button-in-notification) and [Example 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438209/handling-buttons-inside-android-notifications)

Comment: how i add click event on there buttons @Burhanuddin Rashid

Comment: how i add click event on these buttons                .addAction(R.drawable.switches, "Hello", resultIntents)
.addAction(R.drawable.call, "Call", resultIntent)    
@Burhanuddin Rashid

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid Can we add an action button and specify action on the button in notification using FCM?

Answer (score 1):

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // Set Icon
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            // Set Ticker Message
            .setTicker("notification received")
            // Dismiss Notification
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            //.setWhen(0)
            // Set PendingIntent into Notification
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            // Set RemoteViews into Notification
            // .setContent(remoteViews)
            // Set Title
            .setContentTitle("App")
            // show big notification hint when app is open
            //.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            // Set Text
             .setContentText(messageBody)
            // Set Sound
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            // notification button 1
            .addAction(viewAction)
            // notification button 2
            .addAction(rejectAction)
            // notification button 3
            .addAction(approveAction);
```

Here I have added 3 buttons as ".addAction". We can give individual actions for every button it is as follows

```
    NotificationCompat.Action viewAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.view_icon, "View", viewIntentPending).build();
```